# nextjs swr syntax clarification

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm following a tutorial and see the following code:

```
import useSWR from "swr"
import { fetcher } from "./fetcher"

export function useFeed() {
  const { data: feed } = useSWR("/api/feed", fetcher)
  return { feed }
}
```

What's with the `:` between `data` and `feed`? And why is `feed` being returned instead of `data`? I see this semicolon pattern repeated in the nextjs swr documentation. Can someone explain to me what it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `swr` library. This pattern is a part of ES6 syntax and is used to rename a variable while destructuring it (for instance, to avoid a variable name duplication, since `data` is a commonly used name).

You could replace `:` syntax with the following and have the same result:

```
export function useFeed() {
  const feed = useSWR("/api/feed", fetcher).data;
  return { feed };
}
```